# An exercise on (isolated) types

Tags: model-theory

I am currently working through a model theory course and am doing some exercises from Marker's book. I am currently attempting exercise 4.5.2. Which states the following:

Let $T$ be the theory $(\mathbb{Z},s,<)$, where $s(x)=x+1$, i.e. the successor function. I am then asked to determine the types in $S_n(T)$, for all $n$. That means I have to find the complete types.
The second part of the problem is then to figure out which of these types are isolated.
There is only one example in Marker's book and it doesn't help me much with this problem. I find it hard to start just from the definition of a type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge here is to show that :

> $T$ admits quantifiers elimination.

(**Hint :** try to axiomatize $\mathrm{Th}(\mathbb Z,<,s)$ ; show that the models of it [the axiomatization] are of the form $I \times \mathbb Z$ for $I$ a linear order ; then establish a back-and-forth between $\aleph_0$-saturated models [which is kind of easy once you know the form of the models] ; you then have quantifier elimination and completion ; completion assure that your axiomatization is indeed an axiomatization of $\mathrm{Th}(\mathbb Z,<,s)$.)

Then remark that $\mathbb Z$ is a substructure for any model of $T$ (namely if $i \in  I$, $\mathbb Z \simeq \{i\} \times \mathbb Z$). By quantifier elimination, it is then an *elementary* subtructure. So $\mathbb Z$ is a prime model : in particular it is atomic and so realizes exactly the isolated types.

So one way to answer the question is to say that isolated types are those realized by $\mathbb Z$. You can even try to explicit them as the quantifier-free formula are very simple here.

Comment: Ok, I can show quantifier elimination, but I don't completely understand your followup remark.
I understand that $\mathbb{Z}$, without ordering or succesor, is a substructure for any model of $T$ and, by QE, an elementary substructure. Thus, by definition, $\mathbb{Z}$ is prime and thus atomic.
However, I still don't really understand what the types look like. For example, how would I characterize the 1-types, your answer doesn't really seem to provide anything in that direction.

Comment: Secondly, when you say "one way to answer your question is to say that the isolated types are those realized in $\mathbb{Z}$", do you mean that precisely those types $p(\bar{v})$ which contain a formula $\bar{v}=\bar{a}$ for some set $\bar{a}$ from $\mathbb{Z}$ are isolated?

Comment: @matti0006 No, type of $S_n(T)$ are types without parameters, a formula $\bar v = \bar a$ for $\bar a \subset \mathbb Z$ can't be in a type of $S_n(T)$. By type realized in $\mathbb Z$, I mean a type of the form $\mathrm{typ}(\bar a ; \emptyset) := \{ \varphi(\bar v) : \mathbb Z \models \varphi(\bar a) \}$ for some $\bar a \subset \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @matti0006 As for how the types look like, remember that $T$ has quantifiers elimination : a type is entirely charaterized by the quantifier-free formulas that it contains !

Comment: could you please elborate some more, I still don't quite understand this.
As far as I understood an $n$-type is a collection of formulas in at most $n$ free variables. Thus couldn't a $1$-type for example be $p(v):=\{v=1\wedge\neg\phi \text{, for any other formula} \phi\}$,

Comment: Ok, I thought about it some more...I guess you cannot use the formula $v=1$ here since we haven't added constants for $\mathbb{Z}$, thus the only formulas we need to look at are QF formulas. So these would be the possibilities $s(v)$, $v_1<v_2$, $v_1=v_2$ and their negations and conjunctions, is that correct? That still doesn't really give me a description of the type but I might be able to work it out from there. Thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: @matti0006 You are almost correct : $s(v)$ is a term, not an atomic formula. The atomic formulas are $s^m(v_1) < s^n(v_2)$, $s^m(v_1) = s^m(v_2)$, $s^m(v_1) < s^n(v_1)$ and $s^m(v_1) = s^n(v_1)$. Then quantifier-free formulas are finite boolean combination of those.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to approach figuring out what are the types is to remember that two elements are of the same type if <strike>and only if</strike> (the converse only works in homogeneous models such as the monster) there is a structure automorphism between them (make sure you understand why).

First try to understand what are the types of $(\mathbb{Z}, <)$:

Thus, given two tuples of distinct elements their type is reduced to asking what is the order relation between them, and how many elements come in between any two adjacent elements.

Thus, a realized type on $n$ variables $x_1,...,x_n$ which assures that $x_1,...,x_n$ are all different will always have a formula of the form $x_{\sigma(1)} < ... < x_{\sigma(n)}$ where $\sigma$ is a permutation on $1,...,n$.

A realized type which does not assure that all variables are different must contain formulae which tells us which variables are identified (or it would be partial). So an $n$-type with $m$ classes of variables (under the equivalence $x_i~x_j \iff x_i\doteq x_j \in p$) reduces to a type as described above on $m$ variables (this holds in the given theory, as there is no formula $\varphi(x,y)$ which can be solved both by a pair of unique elements and by the same element twice, this can be proven by induction on the complexity of the formula).

Having cleared that out we note that each of these types may be considered a partial type in $(\mathbb{Z},<,s)$ and we may ask how we may complete them.

The successor function allows you to determine the distance between two adjacent elements in the tuple without qauntifiers. So given, for example, a partial type which includes $x_{\sigma(1)}<...<x_{\sigma(1)}$ (which, by the above, determines it completely), it may be extended to include the formulae $x_{\sigma(i)} \doteq s^{n_i}(x_{{\sigma(1)}(i-1)})$ where $n_i$ are positive natural numbers, and these are the only ways to extend it so that it is realized. This in essence means that the realized types in the two theories are the same.

This does not only map all realized type, but demonstrates that they are *all* isolated by the formula which is the conjunction of the (finitely many) formulae we used above to characterize the types (another way to see it is to show that $\mathbb{Z}$ may be embedded in any model of this theory, and so all types realized in $\mathbb{Z}$ are realized in general, and so they have to be isolated by the omitting types theorem)

It remains to ask which types are omitted (remembering, of course, that isolated types may not be omitted, so these will be exactly the non-isolated types).

Recall that an omitted type is a collection of formulae with no element in $\mathbb{Z}$ which solves all of them, but such that any finite conjunction of them does have a solution.

EDIT: Anything below this point is blatantly wrong

This is impossible, though, as for any $n$ the map $k\mapsto n+k:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$ is an isomorphism. This may be used to show that given an arbitrary collection of formulae, all of which have a solution, which are consistent with each other, we may find a tuple which solves all of them.

The bottom line is that all types are isolated.

Comment: Where did the "Deshe" come from?

Comment: Isolated types are necessarily realized in every model. But $\{ x < y \} \cup \{ s^n(x) < y : n \in \mathbb N\}$ isn't realized in $\mathbb Z$. (It is however a partial type as it is finitely realized in $\mathbb Z$.) Am I missing somehting ?

Comment: Actually, I am pretty sure something isn't right in your anwser. There is a theorem stating an equivalence between "All types of every $S_n(T), n \geq 1$ are isolated" and "$T$ is $\aleph_0$-categorical". But here $T$ is clearly not $\aleph_0$-categorical : $\mathbb Z$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z \sqcup_< \mathbb Z$ (every couple in $\mathbb Z$ has finite distance via $s$, which is not true in $\mathbb Z \sqcup_< \mathbb Z$).

Comment: Thank you for this answer as well!

Comment: @Pece Yes, you are of course correct

Comment: It is not correct that two elements have the same type iff there is an automorphism switching them. This is only true in homogenous models, and more generally in saturated models. Standard example: the theory of an equivalence relation with two infinite classes. Take a model with one countable class and the other uncountable. There is no automorphism that takes an element from one class to the other, even though there is a unique $1$-type

Comment: @user115940 I might not have been clear enough, when I said "a structure automorphism between them" I meant a $\sigma$ which maps one to the other (not necessarily the other way around).

Comment: If there's an automorphism that takes $a$ to $b$ then the inverse takes $b$ to $a$. Over the empty set, we can have two equivalence relations on elements: we can say that they are equivalent if their types coincide, and that they are equivalent if there is an automorphism switching them. Clearly, elements that can be switched by an automorphism have the same type. But the converse is not true in general

Comment: @user115940 Uff, I am really bad at communicating myself today apparently. When I said "not necessarily the other way around" I meant that $\sigma$ maps $a$ to $b$ but not necessarily $b$ to $a$.

Comment: The first line says that two elements have the same type iff there is a structure automorphism between them. I take it to mean that $a,b$ have the same type iff there is an automorphism that takes $a$ to $b$. This is the only reasonable interpretation I can see, and it is just wrong :)

Comment: I see my mistake now. Edited. Thanks

Comment: Okay. Not to nitpick but the second line is, I think, also incorrect - the type of a pair is not determined by the order. For example, (1,3) and (1,2) have the same "order type" but they certainly do not have the same type (there's an element between 1 and 3 but not between 1 and 2). Actually, to say that the type of  a tuple is determined by the ordering is exactly to say that the theory $(\mathbb{Z}, <)$ has quantifier elimination. It certainly does not!